# Custom woocommerce payment gateway - Form

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I have a woocommerce platform on which I need to add a custom payment gateway of my bank.
I received the documentation today, and it seems to be a Form I need to integrate on my checkout page. Here is what the form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="https://url.asp" id=form1 name=form1>


<!-- general settings -->

<input type="hidden" name="PSPID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ORDERID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="LANGUAGE" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CN" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="EMAIL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERZIP" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERADDRESS" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERCTY" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERTOWN" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERTELNO" value="">


<!-- security -->


<input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="">

<!-- appearance -->

<input type="hidden" name="TITLE" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BGCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="TXTCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="TBLBGCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="TBLTXTCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BUTTONBGCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BUTTONTXTCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="LOGO" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="FONTTYPE" value="">

<!-- redirect after transaction -->

<input type="hidden" name="ACCEPTURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="DECLINEURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="EXCEPTIONURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="">

<input type="submit" value="" id=submit2 name=submit2>

</form>
```

I have two questions:

- How can I get the user's order ID, amount, currency etc into this form (what variable would I use)?
- How can I get this form added as a payment method on my checkout page ? I've tried a Custom Payment Gateways plugin but it doesn't seem like I can integrate this form with it. The "Pay" button n the checkout needs to to send the form to a specific url if this payment method is selected (I also have Paypal).

Thanks !

Comment: First, The order ID and order data doesn't exist until the order is placed (submitted)… For the rest, you will have to use all available [`WC_Cart` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html), jQuery to get the checkout fields imput data and may be Ajax too… So something complicated and too broad… You should better find an existing plugin as this is a real development.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll contact my bank, I believe they have support for this. I wanted to do it myself but I unfortunately lack the experience and knowledge for this.